# Fractional Factorial Design in R - replicate given matrix

Tags: r, experimental-design

I am trying to reproduce the following fractional factorial design in R.  Each variable has 3 levels and there are 10 variables.  In this design the first 3 variables (A-C) are tested full factorial.

[image: 3 Level 10 Factor fractional factorial design]

I have attempted:

```
library(AlgDesign)

levels.design = c(3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3)
f.design <- gen.factorial(levels.design)

fract.design <- optFederov(
  data=f.design,
  nTrials=sum(levels.design),
  approximate=FALSE)
```

And:

```
    library(DoE.base)
     test.design <-oa.design(nlevels = c(3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3))
```

Which give me 3^10 designs with 27 runs however the first 3 variables are not full factorial.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've managed a potential solution:

Where

Step one I create a full factorial 3^3 matrix

Step two I create a orthogonal 3^7 matrix fixed at 27 runs

Step three merge the two.

```
Full_Factorial <- fac.design(nlevels=3, nfactors=3, randomize=TRUE)

Fractional_Factorial <- oa.design (ID=NULL, nruns=27, replications=1, repeat.only=FALSE,
  randomize = TRUE, seed = 27761, nlevels = c(3,3,3,3,3,3,3), factor.names = list(D=c(1,2,3),
   E=c(1,2,3), F=c(1,2,3), G=c(1,2,3), H=c(1,2,3), I=c(1,2,3), J=c(1,2,3)), columns ="order", 
    min.residual.df = 0)

Merged_matrix <- cbind(Full_Factorial, Fractional_Factorial)
```

There are likley more elegant solutions